# Removing hair from pork belly

Tags: pork

I bought some pork belly yesterday and I was just about to cook it when I saw thick hair on it. I tried to cut it with a sharp serrated knife but it didn't budge. I was really put off and put the pork back in the refrigerator. Can someone please save my pork belly and let me know how to get rid of the hair?

Comment: +1 for *Can someone please save my pork belly?*!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have a blow torch or a brûlée torch, just burn the hairs off.

If this is not an option, I've heard that you can use a normal safety razor. In this case I would definitely choose a razor without a lubricating strip along the top.

Comment: I used the blow torch

Comment: Would a gas stove work in a pinch?

Comment: @Jack Probably, depending how high you can crank the flame.  A gas broiler would likely work too.  The blowtorch will give you more control though, and reduce the amount of inadvertent cooking you're doing.

Comment: helpful! it's my first foray into fresh ham from the local fam and my little piggy has a 5 o'clock shadow lol. . And Easter is tomorrow! lol tx for the help

Comment: so I tried to singe the stubble with a heat gun (heated up to 800 deg). the skin started crackling, but the stubble is still showing.. then tried with a flame from a match...again, some of the stubble shows... any help for stubborn stubble or in grown hairs?